# Are homogeneous rational functions ratios of homogeneous polynomials?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, rational-functions

Suppose that we have a rational function on $\mathbb R^n$
$$
r(x)=\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}
$$
where $q$ has no real roots except $0$, which is a root. Suppose that $r$ is zero homogeneous, meaning that
$$
r(tx)=r(x)\quad\text{ for all }t>0,\,x\neq 0.
$$
We do *not* assume that $p,\,q\in\mathbb R[x]$ are necessarily homogeneous polynomials. Is it the case that there exist *homogenous* polynomials  $\tilde p,\,\tilde q\in\mathbb R[x]$ such that
$$
r(x)=\frac{\tilde p(x)}{\tilde q(x)}?
$$
I have no idea if it matters that $q$ has no non-zero real roots. The same might be true if $r$ has any (integer) homogeneity.

Comment: Doesn't $r(tx)=r(x)\; \forall t,x>0 \implies r(x)$ is a constant?

Comment: Yes, in the one dimensional case. Here $x\in \mathbb R^n$.